# Update collection field and array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update a field and array inside a mongodb collection.

myCollection.

```
{
   position:String,
   users : [String]
}
```

I know how to update the position using:

```
myCollection.updateOne({position:position})
```

I know how to update the users array using:

```
myCollection.updateOne({position:position}, { $addToSet: {users:users})
```

But how to update the two at the same time?

Thanks a lot guys. Backend noob here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `updateOne` is the `filter`, so by running this query:

```
myCollection.updateOne({ position }, { 
    $set: { position: newPosition },
    $addToSet: { users } 
})
```

You should update the `position` of the document with `position` to `newPosition` and add a new `users` to the `users` array

Comment: Thank you man. I am noob and forget to look the method definition!